# Fallback Factory not working to handle Custom Exception in Feign Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, feign

My **requirement is to access the custom exception thrown from first service along with it's body content in the second service**

I have tried 2 things so far, FallbackFactory and ErrorDecoder, out of which **only Fallback factory worked** for me. Error decoder did not have the message of the exception which was thrown from other service. Here is the sample code that I found in another question:

There will be 2 services: inventory-service and product-service

**inventory-service**

*InventoryController.java*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/inventories")
public class InventoryController {

    private final ProductServiceClient productService;

    public InventoryController(ProductServiceClient productService) {
        super();
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> companyInfo() {

        return productService.hello();

    }
}
```

*ProductServiceClient.java*

```
@FeignClient(name = "product-service", url = "http://localhost:9100", fallbackFactory = ProductServiceClientFallback.class)
public interface ProductServiceClient {

    @GetMapping("/products")
    ResponseEntity<?> hello();

}

@Component
class ProductServiceClientFallback implements FallbackFactory<ProductServiceClient> {

    @Override
    public ProductServiceClient create(Throwable cause) {

        return new ProductServiceClient() {

            @Override
            public ResponseEntity<?> hello() {
                System.out.println("hello!! fallback reason was " + cause.getMessage());
                return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
            }

        };
    }

}
```

**product-service**

*ProductController.java*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/products")
public class ProductController {

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() throws Exception {
        if (true) {
            throw new Exception("Service B Exception...");
        }
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

*ProductControllerAdvice.java*

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ProductControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(Exception exception) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Caused due to : " + exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

So, when **/inventories** api is triggered in Inventory controller, it triggers a call to product-service via Feign Client and on product-service side, I throw a custom exception with a message, I have to access that message in my inventory-service.

To get that I have implemented fallback factory and it **worked in a test-workspace** since I got an output like this in console of inventory-service

```
hello!! fallback reason was status 500 reading ProductServiceClient#hello(); content:
Caused due to : Service B Exception...
```

**But, my problem is when I try the similar approach with the applications that I'm working on, I did not get the message of exception, instead I got an out put like this**:

```
reached fallback on workflow side, reason: status 400 reading ProvisioningServiceProxy#executeOrderAction(Long,Long,String)
```

**Service-A**

*TestServiceA.java*

```
@FeignClient( url = "/executeOrder", fallbackFactory = TestServiceAFallback.class )
public interface TestServiceA extends Serializable{
    @PostMapping( value = "order/{requestId}/order/{orderId}/{command}" )
    public ResponseEntity<ProcessInstanceVariable> executeOrderAction(                                                                            @PathVariable( name = "command" ) String command );
}
```

**Service-B** from where the custom exception is thrown

*TestServiceBController.java*

```
@PostMapping( value = /executeOrder )
public ResponseEntity<ProcessInstanceVariable> executeOrderAction(                                                                      @PathVariable( value = "command" ) String command )
{  //switch code to check the command value and throw exception for one particular command
          throw new ValidationException("validation exception from service B");
}
```

I have an advice also, which handles Validation Exceptions and there is a method like this in that class

*TestServiceBControllerAdvice.java*

```
@ExceptionHandler( ValidationException.class )
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleValidationException( ValidationException ve )
{
    return new ResponseEntity<>( ve.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST );
}
```

So, I was expecting to receive the message on TestServiceA side which I sent from TestServiceB, but I received a generic message showing that  BAD REQUEST while reading the API.

I'm not sure if any extra configuration is required on TestServiceA side apart from below configuration:

**testServiceA.properties**

```
feign.hystrix.enabled=true
```

Let me know if anything is missing from my end, I have gone through [this documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-hystrix-fallback) and seems to me I have done the implementation the way it should happen to get the message and body of exception thrown from other service.

Comment: were you able to solve this? if yes please mention how did you solve it? i'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @VishalPatel It's been a while since that, I remember implementing Error decoder only and I was able to get the exception message in response body

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes to this question looking for some answers, I did end up implementing ErrorDecoder, which helped me in capturing the errors. The details are a little fade to me, how the message was caught.
But I used the below code:

```
public class CustomExceptionDecoder implements feign.codec.ErrorDecoder
{
    @Override
    public Exception decode( String methodKey,
                             Response response )
    {
        final ErrorDecoder defaultErrorDecoder = new Default();
        try
        {
            if( response.body() != null )
            {
                byte[] bodyData = Util.toByteArray( response.body().asInputStream() );
                String responseBody = new String( bodyData );
                LOGGER.error( "Error captured in Custom Exception Decoder: ", responseBody );
                return new CustomValidationException( responseBody );
            }
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            LOGGER.error( "Throwing IOException :: {}", e.getCause() );
        }
        return defaultErrorDecoder.decode( methodKey, response );
    }
}
```